# CRM 2013 Iframe Refresh Issue

Tags: javascript, iframe, dynamics-crm

I am using **CRM 2013**. I have added Iframe on FORM. I am showing **custom ASPX page** in **Iframe**. Whenever I create a new record and save Iframe doesn't refresh. When we save the record form refreshes but Iframe doesn't.

I have added the below code to refresh the iframe on save of the record.. but it is not working.. I have tried the same on Load of the form for Update **formtype**. it is not working.

I have tried to add Random Parameters to existing url but didn't work. It is setting **IFrame** Source but does't refreshes the **Iframe**.

```
var IFrame = Xrm.Page.ui.controls.get("IFRAME_test"); 

var Url = IFrame.getSrc();

 Url += (Url.indexOf("?") != -1 ? "&" : "?") + "rnd=" + Math.random();


IFrame.setSrc(Url);
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick for me :

```
document.getElementById("[Your Iframe ID]").src = Xrm.Page.getControl("[Your Iframe ID]").getSrc();
```

Comment: I don't think this is a supported customization, you're manipulating the DOM.